# can't open whatsapp on Lumia 625

Tags: whatsapp, nokia-lumia-625

I'm unable to open my whatsapp.I uninstalled it and reinstalled it.But i still cannot open it.whenever i try opening whatsapp it goes back to home page.

Comment: Tried restarting your phone?